# How to name slightly different methods in PHP so it behaves like ruby "!" (bang)

Tags: php, naming-conventions

It's been a long time I've been thinking on how to deal with this kind of situation:

Take for instance the hash example:

```
hash  = {'a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd'}
other = {'a' => 'd'}

hash.merge(other)  # returns a new hash
hash.merge!(other) # modifies hash
```

How would you deal with that in php?

```
$hash  = new Hash(array( 'a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd' ));
$other = new Hash(array('a' => 'd'));
```

Option params:

```
public function merge($other, array $options = array('mutate' => false))
{

}

// or

public function merge($other, $mutate = false)
{

}
```

Or perhaps two different method names:

```
public function merge($other)
{

}

public function mergeIntoSelf($other)
{

}
```

I kind of like the 'options param' approach, but what if the method actually receives another optional param, like in ruby, which is a modifier callback.

```
$hash->merge($other, function ($key, $originalValue, $otherValue) {
    if ($key === 'foo') {
        return $originalValue;
    }

    return $otherValue;
}, array('mutate' => true));
```

The callback option could be the third one, instead of the second one, but I don't like that. I also don't like the idea of checking the params and trying to find out what is what. They doc block gets hairy.

So I would like to hear your opinions on how you would approach that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd use two different method names instead of one method with a flag parameter. In Ruby `!` is a valid character in an identifier and the convention of using that to mean "modify in place" has been established, in PHP this doesn't exist. So make up any convention you like; e.g.: `mergeInPlace`, `merge_` (please don't), `combine`, `combineWith`, `newWith` or whatever.

Comment: @deceze oh man! This way I will have to come up with more names! =) Well, you made a valid point: ```merge``` and ```merge!``` are two different method names. I will probably stick with that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&` sign at function name but its not a good solition. i want to just give an idea its possible:

```
$a = array( 'a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd' );
$b = array('a' => 'd');
function mergeArray(& $a,$b) {
    return $a = array_merge($a,$b);
}
$c = mergeArray($a,$b);
var_dump($a);
var_dump($c);
```

You can see that $c and $a will be same.

Comment: and i want to mention that you dont need to give the same names for function paramters: it can be like :
`function mergeArray(& $firstArray,$secondArray) {$firstArray = ... }`